# 1 row of primary key column can contain null value?

Tags: null, primary-key

It is said that primary key column can't contain null value bcoz if we allow, then 2 or more null value rows cant be differentiate with each other.
But my ques is that can we allow only 1 null value in primary key column.
So if user try to insert more than 1 null value than it should give error like if we insert (say 1,2 etc .) in a column again then it gives error it is already existing..

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because in Primary key the concept is the column should be `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` so You cant change the `ANSI SQL` stander U can do the the same by making the column as `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 0):

No, primary key cant accept null values.

That's unique key you are talking about, it accepts only one null value. And primary key is unique key without null value.

Also just for information, unique key can be multiple in a table but primary can only be one.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer : Primary Key cannot allow Null entries